How to call a child method after casting an instance from parent to child class?
If I have a class B that inherits from class A and overrides one of its methods, and I have, in TypeScript:
const a: A = new A();
(a as B).toto();

Why is the toto() method that will be called the one implemented in the parent class (i.e. A)?
In TypeScript, I have a class called Drug that has a name and an effiency, and a method updateEfficiency() that decreases efficiency by 1:
class Drug {
  name: string;
  efficiency: number;

  constructor(name: string, efficiency: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.efficiency = efficiency;
  }

  updateEfficiency() {
    this.efficiency -= 1;
  }

}

I have another class called BottleOfWine that inherits from Drug class and overrides the updateEfficiency() method:
class BottleOfWine extends Drug {

  constructor(efficiency: number) {
    super("Old bottle of wine", efficiency);
  }

  updateEfficiency() {
    this.efficiency -= 2;
  }

}

I have a third class called Inventory which contains an array of Drug, and a method updateAll()that updates the efficiency of all the drugs:
class Inventory {

  drugs: Drug[];

  constructor(drugs: Drug[]) {
    this.drugs = drugs;
  }

  updateAll() {
    this.drugs.forEach((drug) => {
      switch (drug.name) {
        case "Old bottle of wine":
          // here I expect to call the child method that decreases the efficiency by 2,
          // but the parent class is called instead
          (drug as OldBottleOfWine).updateEfficiency();
          break;
        case "Insulin vial":
          // nothing to do
          break;
      }
    });
  }

}

On the updateAll() method, I want, depending on the name of the drug, to cast the drug object into a more specific object (child) and call the method of the child class.
Example:
const inventory = new Inventory([new Drug("Old bottle of wine", 10)])
inventory.updateAll();
console.log(inventory.drugs[0].efficiency); // I expected 8 (ie 10 - 2), but got 9 (ie 10 - 1)

How could you explain it?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. (B a).toto(); is not valid TS at all. DrugNames and OldBottleOfWine are missing. Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] which, when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs, demonstrates your issue clearly without having other unrelated issues.

drug as OldBottleOfWine is a type assertion - TypeScript does not exist at runtime, so it can't do any casting or conversion. It's not at all clear to me what you actually want here, because if the child class overrides the method then simply drug.updateEfficiency() will call it (and call the inherited implementation if not).

Prev comment is correct; if you want to do this (and it's not necessarily clear that it's safe to do that, but whatever) then you need to actually call the method you care about, like BottleOfWine.prototype.updateEfficiency.call(drug); as shown in this playground link. Type assertions don't do anything at runtime. Does that fully address the question? If so I (or jonrshape) can write up an answer (or find a suitable dupe target). If not, what's missing?

Fundamentally the problem is that new Drug("Old bottle of wine", 10) is not the same as new BottleOfWine(10). Why don't you instantiate the class you actually want it to be?

Because from where the inventory is made up, we aren't mean to know each kind of drugs available (ie all the inherited classes from Drug). Imagine that people that fills and creates inventory with an array of drugs only know Drug implementation and not the inherited classes, and from the name you want to call different methods from the child classes

Then you should create instances of Drug an distinguish them by values inside it (like efficiencyRating = -2 for Wine) and a generic method (updateEfficiency(){ this.efficiency-= this.efficiencyRating; }, since you cannot know which class to use.

• How does the caller of new Inventory() not know BottleOfWine when they know "Old bottle of wine"? • Could you respond to this comment so I know how to proceed here?

The control here is with those people who create the inventory or the drug objects. If they create Drug object you will only call methods from Drug class even if you typecast to any of the child classes. If you need child class methods to be called, then the object should specifically be that of the child class (or BottleOfWine instance). You may want to explore the factory method pattern in creating the Drug objects. If you have the right factory method, those people may not have to worry about the inherited classes.

@user25018137 ... The entire point of polymorphism and inheritance is that one can expect every drug-item to have its drug type specific updateEfficiency method. The Inventory's updateAll method should not even try to make assumptions about the drug-items as long as it's clear that the very drugs array exclusively contains drug type specific instances. Just let it do ... this.drugs.forEach(drug => drug.updateEfficiency());.

@user25018137 ... Regarding the OP's use case ... new Drug("Old bottle of wine", 10) does create a Drug but not a BottleOfWine instance. Thus, the result seen by the OP, an efficiency value of 9 is exactly how it should be. The question is, why does the OP want to distinguish drug types by an arbitrary name? A drug item's name is nothing one can rely on. The drug item's type (determined by the class constructor function) is the only reliable criteria. The OP needs another approach for letting people create the correct drug type instances or a better explanation of the entire matter.

Targeting my 2nd comment ...

... Regarding the OP's use case ... new Drug("Old bottle of wine", 10) does create a Drug but not a BottleOfWine instance. Thus, the result seen by the OP, an efficiency value of 9 is exactly how it should be. The question is, why does the OP want to distinguish drug types by an arbitrary name? A drug item's name is nothing one can rely on. The drug item's type (determined by the class constructor function) is the only reliable criteria. The OP needs another approach for letting people create the correct drug type instances or a better explanation of the entire matter.

One possible solution of controlling, how drug instances are created is to not use sub-classing at all. In case of a sole Drug class implementation nothing can be confused. In addition one would change the implementation to an additionally to be provided parameter which reflects the in/decrease of a drug item's efficiency value ...


const inventory = new Inventory([
  new Drug("Old bottle of wine", 10, -2),
  new Drug("Homegrown Weed", 20, -1),
]);

console.log({
  drugList: structuredClone(inventory.drugs),
});
inventory.updateAll();

console.log({
  drugList: structuredClone(inventory.drugs),
});
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
<script>
class Drug {

  constructor(name = '', efficiency = 0, efficiencyDelta = 0) {

    name = String(name);
    efficiency = Number(efficiency);
    efficiencyDelta = Number(efficiencyDelta);

    Object.assign(this, { name, efficiency, efficiencyDelta });
  }
  updateEfficiency() {

    this.efficiency += this.efficiencyDelta;
  }
}

class Inventory {

  constructor(drugs = []) {
    this.drugs = Array.from(drugs);
  }
  updateAll() {
    this.drugs.forEach(drug => drug.updateEfficiency())
  }
}
</script>



